# Delete folders older than 30 days without recursive approach of deleting sub folders in windows batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to delete folders within a directory older than 30 days. I dont want to check for sub folders within. If the folder is older than 30 days, then output the folder name to a log file. Right now I am getting even the sub folder name in my log file with this code:

```
forfiles -p %DIR% -d -30 -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path && echo @path>>%LOG_DIR%"
```

If I take out /S, it says that the folder is not empty and doesn't do anything. Is there any way to write only the main folder name to log file and also delete them all?

Comment: /M ? `forfiles -p %DIR% -d -30 /M "*.*" -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path && echo @path>>%LOG_DIR%"`

Comment: Is that an answer? /M? what does it do?

Comment: if it was answer, I would have posted it as one. :) /m Searches files according to a searchmask.

Comment: Can you tell me how to just output folder name to a file without deleting them.. Just the main folders, not the sub folders.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. `rd /S /Q` does not output anything, and `echo @path` only returns every processed item (folder). Are you sure you do *not* have `forfiles -s` in your true script?

Comment: No, it is not there @aschipfl

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, `/M` defaults to `*` if not stated. `forfiles` supidly behaves differently with wild-cards with respect to most other commands (for the sake of inconsistency??): while usually `*.*` matches also items without extension (like `file`), `forfiles /M *.*` only matches files with an extension of at least a character; hence I do not recommend to use `/M *.*`...

Comment: dir %HFM_DIR% /a:d /b>%LOG_DIR%

This helps in displaying all folders. Is there a way I can display only for old folders (like 30 days or something)